# I want to create a monitoring file for wireguard server

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want to create a sort of monitoring for wireguard and here are the inputs where from I can get some information.

The server configuration file: wghub.conf:

```
# Hub configuration created on arm-sigma on Tue Feb 20 15:38:55 CET 2024
[Interface]
Address = 10.88.188.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SaveConfig = false
MTU = 1280
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -i wghub -j ACCEPT;iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.88.188.0/24 -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE;
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wghub -j ACCEPT;iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.88.188.0/24 -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE;
PostUp = sysctl -q -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
PostDown = sysctl -q -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0

# 11: samsung > wgclient_samsung.conf
[Peer]
PublicKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PresharedKey = yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
AllowedIPs = 10.88.188.11/32

# 12: ultra > wgclient_ultra.conf
[Peer]
PublicKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PresharedKey = yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
AllowedIPs = 10.88.188.12/32

# 13: mi10 > wgclient_mi10.conf
[Peer]
PublicKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PresharedKey = yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
AllowedIPs = 10.88.188.13/32

# 15: drunksorrow > wgclient_drunksorrow.conf
[Peer]
PublicKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PresharedKey = yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
AllowedIPs = 10.88.188.15/32

# 16: win11 > wgclient_win11.conf
[Peer]
PublicKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PresharedKey = yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
AllowedIPs = 10.88.188.16/32
```

The output of the command: `:~ wg show wghub`

```
interface: wghub
  public key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  preshared key: (hidden)
  endpoint: 1.2.3.4:60237
  allowed ips: 10.88.188.13/32
  latest handshake: 3 minutes, 7 seconds ago
  transfer: 4.24 MiB received, 37.52 MiB sent

peer: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  preshared key: (hidden)
  allowed ips: 10.88.188.11/32

peer: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  preshared key: (hidden)
  allowed ips: 10.88.188.12/32

peer: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  preshared key: (hidden)
  allowed ips: 10.88.188.15/32

peer: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  preshared key: (hidden)
  allowed ips: 10.88.188.16/32
```

I can see an active peer in this example wg internal IP 10.88.188.13 with public IP 1.2.3.4 connected to the server and Last Seen 3 minutes, 7 seconds ago. Ofc more clients can be connected in the same time.

All I want is to grab the necessary info from what I can use as input to see exactly who is connected on my server.

I want to create a bash script to run in crontab once per minute in order to create a txt file which should looks like this (and to reflect the active connections):

```
Client: mi10, Endpoint: 1.2.3.4:60237, Latest Handshake: 3 minutes, 7 seconds ago
```

This txt file will be called by a php script with shell_exec to be posted into an administration web page.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: please update the question with your coding attempts at trying to join/match the two data sets

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, once you pull `awk` into the mix you can usually eliminate the need for other tools like `cat`, `(e)grep`, `cut`, `tr`, `sed`, and in this case `xargs`.  `awk` is also quite useful when trying to join/match different files. Net result: OP's entire process can probably be performed with a single `awk` script (which in turn is going to be more efficient than the current method).

OP hasn't (yet) provided a copy of `wghub.conf` so I've reverse engineered OP's code to come up with a file which, when fed to OP's `cat/egrep/grep/awk/cut/tr/xargs` pipeline, will generate the same set of hostname/ip pairs:

```
$ cat wghub.conf
.conf      _____         samsung/__________
.conf      configuration
AllowedIPs _____         10.88.188.11/__________
.conf      _____         ultra/__________
.conf      configuration
AllowedIPs _____         10.88.188.12/__________
.conf      _____         mi10/__________
.conf      configuration
AllowedIPs _____         10.88.188.13/__________
.conf      _____         drunksorrow/__________
.conf      configuration
AllowedIPs _____         10.88.188.15/__________
.conf      _____         win11/__________
.conf      configuration
AllowedIPs _____         10.88.188.16/__________
.conf      _____         jderu/__________
.conf      configuration
AllowedIPs _____         10.88.188.17/__________

$ cat wghub.conf | egrep '.conf|AllowedIPs' | grep -v configuration | awk '{print $3}'|cut -d "/" -f1|tr "\n" " "|xargs -n 2
samsung 10.88.188.11
ultra 10.88.188.12
mi10 10.88.188.13
drunksorrow 10.88.188.15
win11 10.88.188.16
jderu 10.88.188.17
```

I've also added a bogus line to OP's crontab output to demonstrate leaving an ip address alone if there is no match in `wghub.conf`

```
$ cat crontab.out
Client: 10.88.188.13, Latest Handshake: 1 minute, 42 seconds
Client: 10.88.188.16, Latest Handshake: 51 minutes, 32 seconds
Client: 99.99.99.99, Latest Handshake: 99 minutes, 99 seconds
```

One `awk` approach to replacing all of OP's current code that also performs the match with the crontab output:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { if ( $0 ~ /[.]conf|AllowedIPs/ ) {    # 1st file: match lines on ".conf|AllowedIPs"
             if ( $0 ~ /configuration/ )        # if there is an additional match on "configuration" then ...
                next                            # skip to next input line from 1st file

             sub("/.*","",$3)                   # strip trailing "/..." from 3rd feld

             if (name) {                        # if name is populated then ...
                ip_name[$3","] = name           # add entry to array ($3==ip at this point)
                name = ""                       # clear name
             }
             else
                name = $3                       # else save 3rd field as name
          }
          next                                  # skip to next input line from 1st file
        }

($2 in ip_name) { sub($2,ip_name[$2]) }         # 2nd file: if ip($2) is an index in the ip_name[] array then
                                                # replace ip (in current line) with contents of ip_name[ip]

1                                               # 2nd file: print current line
' wghub.conf crontab.out
```

**NOTE:** updated with suggestions from Ed Morton.

This generates:

```
Client: mi10, Latest Handshake: 1 minute, 42 seconds
Client: win11, Latest Handshake: 51 minutes, 32 seconds
Client: 99.99.99.99, Latest Handshake: 99 minutes, 99 seconds
```

**NOTES:**

- the title mentions *`I want to replace something in a file`* but it's not clear (to me) if OP wants to update the file containing the crontab output
- if OP has access to `GNU awk` (aka `gawk`) then it would be possible to use the `-i inplace` feature to update the crontab file; OP can read up on that and ask a new question if there are issues getting it to work (it's a bit more involved when you only want to update some of the files fed to `awk`)
- the easiest/quickest coding solution would be to direct the `awk` output to a tmpfile, (optional) make a backup copy of `crontab.out`, then `cp tmpfile crontab.out`

Comment: ++ especially for taking the time to recreate that `wghub.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the initial question, I know is not an elegant solution but it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
            
wg show wghub | \
awk ' \
/peer:/ {pid=$2} \
/endpoint:/ {endpoint=$2} \
/latest handshake:/ {handshake=$3" "$4" "$5" "$6; printf "Client: %s| Endpoint: %s| Latest Handshake: %s\n", substr(allowed, 1, length(allowed)-3), endpoint, handshake} \
/allowed ips:/ {allowed=$3}' >  mon1.txt
            
cat  wghub.conf | egrep '.conf|AllowedIPs' | grep -v configuration | awk '{print $3}'|cut -d "/" -f1|tr "\n" " "|xargs -n 2 >  mon2.txt
#same result as bove:
#awk '/.conf|AllowedIPs/ && !/configuration/{split($3,a,"/"); printf "%s%s", a[1], (++cnt % 2 ? OFS : ORS)}' wghub.conf  > mon2.txt
            
            
while IFS="|" read -r client endpoint handshake; do
    ip=$(echo $client | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d " " -f2)
    name=$(grep $ip  mon2.txt | awk '{print $1}')
    echo "Client: $name, $endpoint, $handshake"
done <  mon1.txt >  mon3.txt
```

The desired result which shows Endpoint as well:

```
cat mon3.txt
Client: mi10, Endpoint: 1.2.3.4:60237, Latest Handshake: 3 minutes, 7 seconds ago
Client: samsung,  Endpoint: 5.6.7.8:49428,  Latest Handshake: 54 minutes, 32 seconds
```

mon1.txt and mon2.txt are "temporary" files but they don't bother me at all.
I'm sure more efficient solution can be applied as well.

Comment: Regarding "I tried to combine all" - I don't see anything in your answer suggested by any of the answers. Copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and it'll tell you of some issues. See also [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). You don't need a bunch of other commands and pipelines and a shell loop and temp files when you're using awk. @markp-fuso's single awk script does everything you need concisely, portably, efficiently and robustly.

Comment: this answer has introduced additional inputs (`wg show wghub`) and patterns (`peer:`, `endpoint:`, `latest hardshake:` and `allowed ips:`) that are not mentioned in the question; how are we supposed to come up with a workable solution if you aren't going to provide all necessary inputs to understand the issue?

Comment: ... and then there's the new component (`Endpoint:`) added to the expected result, also not part of the original question

Comment: I have edited the initial question, I wasn't expected such a professional approach, many thanks for all the explanations and sorry for the initial question, I wasn't inspired at all.